# How to use DNS in ingress

Tags: kubernetes

I deploy an ingress with `app1` and `app2`.

```
example.com/app1  ---> app1
example.com/app2  ---> app2
```

And define /etc/hosts in all the machine.

```
192.168.1.10    example.com
```

But i want to know in operation how can i use **DNS** and ingress.

What should i do?
What ingress bring to me?
I confused by ingress. How should i use it in practical envinroment?

Answer (score 6):

With DNS you can't just use `example.com` (`example.com` is owned by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/)). You have to own the DNS configured on your ingress. For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 4200
```

In the case above you have to own `mydomain.com`. You can buy your domain at any major [domain registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) like [GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com).

Then you will have to expose your Ingress externally depending on the setup you have (AWS, bare-metal, etc) with a [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) Kubernetes Service and have an [A, or CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) entry on your domain registrar manager, point to that external endpoint (for `mydomain.com`). For example, on AWS that entry would be a CNAME that looks like this: `xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`

Note: You can ignore the host altogether but the ingress will only service a default backend as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) with a minimal ingress resource. As far as using your own DNS server, just you can too, as long as your DNS server correctly resolves mydomain.com to the external IP that your ingress controller is fronting.

Hope it helps!

Comment: can i have DNS server and do not using domain name in ingress?

Comment: you can ignore the host altogether but the ingress will only service a `default` backend as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource).   DNS server, just you can as long as your DNS server correctly resolves `mydomain.com` to the external IP of your ingress controller

Comment: I've installed nginx ingress via helm from https://helm.nginx.com/stable (created a chart setting ingress-nginx as a dependency, added values-overwrites.yaml, run `helm install nginx-ingress . -f values-overwrites.yaml -n nginx --create-namespace`), but I'm puzzled where should I put `spec:` bit to? What is the file you are describing after `For example:`? (or: where/how it is applied?)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option that can configure your DNS provider automatically - you can install the External-DNS resource. No affiliation, I have simply found it useful.

You will need:

- A Kubernetes cluster
- A domain registered with a supported DNS provider
- The kubectl command-line tool installed and configured

**Install and Configure the External-DNS resource**

External-DNS installed on your cluster will need to interact with your DNS provider. To configure External-DNS, you'll need to provide extra information regarding your DNS provider via a values.yaml file, as documented [here.](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/external-dns). First, you need to configure your DNS provider or take note of your DNS provider information. Then, with this information, you can deploy the External-DNS controller in your cluster passing the information via the values.yaml file. You will need to read the documentation of your DNS provider and External-DNS to know what information to provide and in what format, as External-DNS expects different keys and values for different providers. This is an example of how to install using Helm:

```
#values.yaml
---
provider: aws
aws:
  secretAccessKey:
    secretName: external-dns-aws-credentials
    secretKey: aws_secret_access_key
  accessKeyId:
    secretName: external-dns-aws-credentials
    secretKey: aws_access_key_id
```

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm repo update
helm install external-dns bitnami/external-dns -f values.yaml --namespace external-dns --create-namespace
```

**How to use External-DNS**

Now that External-DNS is installed and configured, it will automatically create DNS records for Ingress and Service resources with the use of an annotation. For exmaple, to create an Ingress resource use the following annotation to automatically create a DNS record for the specified hostname:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
  external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: my-app.example.com
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-app-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

[Here is their cool FAQ.](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/faq.md)

Answer (score 0):

I deployed a set of 10 or 12 services on K8s and needed a way to expose them to a mobile client. I could create a service of the type loadBalancer for each service, but it would requires to have 10 or more loadBalancers on AWS, all of them pointing to the same set of machines. Instead of that, It was created just one service of type loadBalancer, the ingress service, which depending of the path redirects to the appropriate service. 
The ingress is used for access outside the cluster, inside you can access using the cluster DNS. For example: my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local.

Check this link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

And also this one: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: so ingress and loadbalancer do same thing?

Comment: i do not have loud provider

Comment: K8s is designed for the cloud, so it is necessary to make some workarounds on premises. I am running it on amazon and k8s automaticallly creates a loadbalancer for me.

Comment: LoadBalancer divides the traffic in machine level, for each node. The ingress forward the incoming request to the right service, using the same load balancer.

Comment: service also can divide traffic to diffrent node

Comment: service sends traffic to each pod, which can be in a different node, we are talking at k8s level, already inside the cluster. Load balancer acts in physical ips.